# Post only returning older result

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

So I have a posting system. The issue is when the user posts say `Hi`, it doesn't show up till they submit another post. Then `Hi` shows up, but the other post doesn't. So I guess you could call it a "delay"? Here's how I'm retrieving from the DB

```
<?php 
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $stmt1 = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM likes WHERE liked_post_id = :id;");
        $stmt1->bindValue(':id', $row['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $likes = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         echo  $row['post_content'].'-'.time_ago($row['post_date']).'-'.$likes['count'];
     ?>
```

And I check in the DB and theres one record right now, and then I checked the page and theres no post. So Any ideas would be great. I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: can you add the "$stmt" query? The insert into posts table too (even the transaction calls, if used)

Comment: Can you give us a little more code? Maybe you fetched row twice, like one time before while loop and second time in while loop. I made this mistake some time ago. In that case, you are losing last post in first fetch.

Comment: If the INSERT is happening before your SELECT, using the same connection, then odds are high that the INSERT was not auto-committed, causing the SELECT to pull old data, and then the INSERT got committed at your script's EOL.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly you have the entry in your database but it is not shown on your page until you make another POST. When you make POST your page gets refreshed and you see the previous POST. If you add a bit of PHP code (for example: `header("Location: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']");` ) to manually refresh the page after a POST you should see it right away.